# Не открывается админка umi.cms

Tags: php, redirect, umi

При попытке зайти в админку, после ввода логина:пароля отображается белый экран без всего.
Включил debug, выводятся следующие строчки:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/u22245/cote-cateringru/www/classes/modules/def_module.php:1) in
>   /home/u22245/cote-cateringru/www/classes/system/subsystems/streams/ulang/ulangStream.php
>   on line 257
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/u22245/cote-cateringru/www/classes/modules/def_module.php:1) in
>   /home/u22245/cote-cateringru/www/classes/system/subsystems/buffers/HTTPOutputBuffer.php on line 170
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/u22245/cote-cateringru/www/classes/modules/def_module.php:1) in
>   /home/u22245/cote-cateringru/www/classes/system/subsystems/buffers/HTTPOutputBuffer.php on line 173
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/u22245/cote-cateringru/www/classes/modules/def_module.php:1) in
>   /home/u22245/cote-cateringru/www/classes/system/subsystems/buffers/HTTPOutputBuffer.php on line 129

Судя по вики umi.cms дело в редиректах, но не могу найти в чём.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Написано, что в первой строке файла def_module.php начинается вывод данных клиенту. Перед этим клиенту автоматически отдаются все заголовки, после чего функция header будет вызывать ошибку как у вас. Посмотрите, что там в этом файле. Может редактировали его и случайно пробел в начале вписали.

Comment: Или кодировка UTF-8 BOM

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov Да, дело было в кодировке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась сохранением def_module.php в UTF-8 без BOM

Comment: Для полноты ответа я бы дописал "в UTF-8 без BOM".

Comment: насколько помню, такая же ошибка может быть при наличии пробельных символов вне php-кода в php-файлах. Например пробел или перенос строки после "?>" или перед "<?php"

Comment: @ArthurShiriev, да, такая проблема тоже была, но в этот раз пробелов не было.